# Multiple custom cell in TableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

Scenario

---

| First Cell    |

---

---

| Second Cell   |
|    SWITCH     |
|               |

---

---

| Third Cell    |
|  TextField    |

---

I created a dynamic table view with three different classes: `SecondTableCell` (inside it has the outlet of a switch) and `ThirdTableCell` (inside it has an outlet of a textField)

The switch is Off.

I need to see `textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` then the switch is turned on.

How can I do this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var customTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellSwitch = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSwitch")! as! SwitchTableViewCell
        let cellText = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellText")! as! TextFieldTableViewCell

}

class SwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var switchOutlet: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn == true{
            print("swithOn")
        }else{
            print("swithOff")
        }
    }

}


class TextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldColor: UITextField!
}
```

Comment: Are you only going to have two cells in your whole tableView? In that case you don't need a tableview, just a textfield and a switch would do.

Comment: I need to have the switch in a dynamic cell and the text field in another dynamic cell too

Comment: yes is for exercize

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have? My answer assumes that you already have a view that shows up when you compile, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: inside cellForRowAt I have 
  let cellSwitch = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSwitch")! as! SwitchTableViewCell

Comment: and let cellText = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellText")! as! TextFieldTableViewCell

Comment: if cellSwitch.switchOutlet.isOn == true{
        print("swithHere")
    }else{
        print("swithHere2")
    }
 THIS CODE DOSNT WORK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SwitchDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var customTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cellSwitch = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSwitch")! as! SwitchTableViewCell
        let cellText = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellText")! as! TextFieldTableViewCell

        cellSwitch.delegate = self
        cellText.delegate = self
    }

    func valueDidChange(isOn: Bool) {
        tableView.visibleCells.forEach { cell
            if let cell = cell as? TextFieldTableViewCell {
                cell.textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

}

protocol SwitchDelegate {
    func valueDidChange(isOn: Bool)
}

class SwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var switchOutlet: UISwitch!
    var delegate: SwitchDelegate?

    @IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        delegate?.valueDidChange(isOn: sender.isOn)
    }
} 


class TextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
}
```

Comment: I try to implement this but have some problem with extend

Comment: It'd be helpful it you would say which problem and not just mention that you had a problem. Please edit your original question and post your code.

Comment: that is now the important part of the code that you need to modify.

Comment: there are 2 error, first Value of type 'SwitchTableViewCell' has no member 'delegate' and Value of type 'TextFieldTableViewCell' has no member 'delegate', the second is Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'

Comment: work but I need last step because cell.textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false do a runtime error, Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, but I don t add cellText.delegate = self, because there aren't

Comment: in your code you named the `textField` `textFieldColor` first. If you renamed it, remove the reference from the .xib file and add it again. It sounds like you are accessing `textField` and it does not exist.

Comment: you know if there are other information for implement the protocol because is very important, today I have learn something new

Comment: This solution is a bit time consuming due to the forEach loop to find the textField cell. Why don't you create cross-reference between the switch cell and the textField cell. Using that you can gain processor time by directly calling the tableViewCell functions via the references.

Comment: This is not a real time scenario, it’s homework. The obvious situation would be to have the textField and the switch in the same cell. She only has 5 cells, so processor will survive that. But yes, you are right that there several ways to optimize this solution.

Comment: How call the cell 4 with out the for ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question. Could you ask someone to help you with the translation?

Comment: how can I refer to the cell I know is 4, instead of doing the for each

Comment: Without the each, it'd be something like `tableView.cellForRow(at: tableView.indexPath(for: TextFieldTableViewCell))`. But what Endre means is giving the switch cell a reference of the text field cell (`var textFieldCell: TextFieldTableViewCell`) at initialisation and then forgetting about the delegate. The switch cell would have access to the textFieldCell and could access it when the switch is changed. I don't like that option as it's a bad practice. Cells should be dynamic and should be reusable. But then again, your whole task has no resemblance with real-life problems

Answer (score 0):

When you setup the cells in the tableviewcontroller, you can define at view row you want to use which tableviewcell class. Just like in my below example:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if ((indexPath.row < 25 && counter > 25) || (indexPath.row < counter)) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SaleItems", for: indexPath) as! MyTableCellTableViewCell
        let TapRecognize = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.PictureTap(sender:)))
        TapRecognize.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        TapRecognize.name = jSonData[indexPath.row]["advid"]

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.Megnevezes.text=jSonData[indexPath.row]["advdescription"]!
        cell.EladasiAr.text=jSonData[indexPath.row]["advprice"]! + " " + jSonData[indexPath.row]["advpricecur"]!
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(TapRecognize)
        cell.LoadPicture(AdvID: Int(jSonData[indexPath.row]["advid"]!)!)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PagerCell", for: indexPath) as! ChangePageCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

}
```

In my example the last row of the tableview is different. It is not exactly clear from your explanation what do you really want to do with the switch cell. But you should ensure that you can identify the cells and their classes to know where to pass the action's.

In my case the gestureRecognizer gets a name, which contains a relevant advertisement ID to load the photos, linked to that advertisement details.

When you tap on the cell, it calls the tap recogniser's action and name can be used to identify which cell is touched.